# Is the polynomial $(2x+2)$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Is the polynomial $(2x + 2)$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

I know that the units in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are $\pm$1.

Please check my proof below:

Suppose $f$ = $(2x + 2)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$[x] is a degree 1-polynomial. Then $f=1(2x + 2)$ where $g = 1$ and $h = (2x + 2)$ for $g, h$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$[$x$]. Since $g$ is a unit, we have $f =\text{unit}\cdot$degree-$1$ polynomial. Hence $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ .

Comment: I get that $2x+2=2(x+1)$. That looks like a non-trivial factorisation to me.

Comment: The units in $\Bbb Z[x]$ are $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Then can I instead say, Suppose *f* = $(2x + 2)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$[$x$] is a degree 1-polynomial. Then *f* = $1(2x + 2)$ where *g* = 1 and *h* = $(2x + 2)$ for *g, h* $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$. Since *g* is a unit, we have *f* = unit$\cdot$degree-1 polynomial. Hence *f* is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: "Since $g$ is a unit, we have $f$ = unit⋅degree-1 polynomial. Hence $f$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z$." The second sentence doesn't follow here; not all degree-one polynomials are irreducible over $\Bbb Z[x]$. In particular, $2x+2$ is a counterexample. What you're saying is true over $F[x]$ for $F$ a field though!

Comment: @HenrySwanson I'm not sure why $(2x + 2)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$[$x$]. Can you point me in the right direction please? Thanks!

Comment: $x=2(x + 1)$ and both $2$ and $x + 1$ are polynomials (none of them invertible, and hence no unit)

Comment: Something is irreducible if it can be factored into two factors, both of which are non-units. Since neither $2$ nor $x+1$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z$, $2x+2$ is not irreducible.

Comment: How would this change if instead of $\mathbb{Z}$[$x$] it was $\mathbb{Q}$[$x$]? I was looking online that Einstein's Irreducibility Criterion might suffice but since $(2x + 2)$ is a degree-1 polynomial would we even need Einstein's Irreducibility Criterion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The conditions for Eisenstein's (not Einstein's) Criterion are not met by $2x+2$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Can I use Gauss' Lemma here? Since $(2x + 2)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$[$x$], $(2x + 2)$ must be reducible in $\mathbb{Q}$[$x$].

Comment: Any $f\in \Bbb Z[x]$ is reducible in $\Bbb Z[x]$ if $f=g\cdot h$ for some non-zero $g,h\in \Bbb Z[x]$ such that neither $g$ nor $h$ has a multiplicative inverse in $\Bbb Z[x]$.... E.g. $g=2$ and $h=x+1.$

Comment: In Gauss' Lemma the definition of "reducible in $\Bbb Z[x]$" is different.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is incorrect - you display one factorisation in which one of the factors is a unit. However to be irreducible you have to consider all possible factorisations.

As in the comments the factorisation $2x+2=2(x+1)$ is a factorisation into non-units in $\mathbb Z[x]$ which shows that the polynomial is reducible.

The situation in $\mathbb Q[x]$ is different, because $2$ is a unit in this context.

You don't need Eisenstein here - since the product of polynomials has degree the sum of the degrees, and a linear polynomial has degree $1$ the only possible factors have degree $0$ (constants) or $1$. If there is a factorisation in the $\mathbb Z$ context, one of the factors must be a constant, and this will be a product of primes. The prime factors of the constant must clearly be factors of each of the coefficients of the polynomial, and any prime which divides the coefficients leads to a factorisation.

In the $\mathbb Q$ context every constant other than $0$ is a unit, so a non-trivial factorisation into irreducibles must involve two factors of degree greater than $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. So in $\mathbb{Q}$[$x$], implementing what you said, $(2x + 2)$ = $2(x + 1)$ which is a factorization of a degree-0 (2) polynomial with a degree-1 $(x + 1)$ polynomial. Hence, $(2x + 2)$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$[$x$] as $2(x + 1)$ is factored as a degree-0 polynomial $\cdot$ a degree-1 polynomial.

Comment: @yagayeet In $\mathbb Q[x]$ we have $2\times \frac 12=1$ so that $2$ is a unit. In this context $2x+2$ is an associate of $x+1$ and both are irreducible.

Answer (score -1):

$(2x+2)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

To see why let's start with the definition.

An element $f$ in a commutative ring $R$ is called irreducible if there does not exist non-units(Or non-invertible elements) $x$ and $y$ such that $f = xy$.

Thus an element is reducible if it can be written as the product of two non units.

We can write $2x+2$ as $2 * (x+1)$, both of which are non-units in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.(The only units in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are $1$ and $-1$). Thus $2x+2$ is reducible.